# Comparing time-series data for single day of week

Tags: time-series, anomaly-detection

Comparing time-series data for single day of week

I've been provided time-series data for customer wait time (seconds) taken at 5 minute intervals for 15 separate Tuesdays from this year (midnight to midnight) selected to avoid any seasonal impacts on the data.

After plotting the data there is a morning and afternoon peak of pretty consistent length and amount.

The question I've been asked to answer is for a new data point is the wait time considered 'normal'. That is, if a new wait time value is similar to historical values for the same time it is considered normal, if it is very different it can be flagged as abnormal. What process do I need to undertake to establish this?

Is the data I have enough to draw conclusions for a similar Tuesday (no seasonal effects)? More involved analysis (and access to full data) is dependent on getting somewhere with this data.

Obviously I don't have a great stats knowledge but I'm handy with Python/Excel etc so I'm confident once I'm headed in the right direction I should be able to get somewhere.

Comment: "15 separate Tuesdays from this year (midnight to midnight) selected to avoid any seasonal impacts on the data." -- I don't understand how this avoids seasonal impacts?

Comment: @alex Fair question, I might have not used the right terminology. The weeks are typical. The influences we see are generally only from public holidays, easter, xmas holidays etc. These are avoided in the dataset. It probably inst perfect, but it is the data I have.

Comment: I don't have any personal experience with this, but I know that some time series models can be used for anomaly detection instead of for forecasting. https://www.datascience.com/blog/python-anomaly-detection